# What are all of the html2canvas callback events?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to find all **html2canvas** callback events which can be passed in the optional options argument, but so far I only found one (`onrendered`). I'm pretty sure there are more, but I didn't find any in the documentation.

```
html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I need to find events that happen before and after render.

Comment: have you tried finding and reading the documentation?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've been a bit busy. Anyway, yes I did, but they did not mention it anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**oncanplay** - Script to be run when a file is ready to start playing (when it has buffered enough to begin)

**oncanplaythrough** - Script to be run when a file can be played all the way to the end without pausing for buffering

**oncuechange** - Script to be run when the cue changes in a  element

**ondurationchange** - Script to be run when the length of the media changes

**onemptied** - Script to be run when something bad happens and the file is suddenly unavailable (like unexpectedly disconnects)

**onended** - Script to be run when the media has reach the end (a useful event for messages like "thanks for listening")

**onerror** - Script to be run when an error occurs when the file is being loaded

**onloadeddata** - Script to be run when media data is loaded

**onloadedmetadata** - Script to be run when meta data (like dimensions and duration) are loaded

**onloadstart** - Script to be run just as the file begins to load before anything is actually loaded

**onpause** -   Script to be run when the media is paused either by the user or programmatically

for more look at [w3school.xy](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Comment: I see, so it takes standard html events to work. Did I miss it somewhere in the docs, or was I just supposed to magically make that connection? Anyway, thanks for your help.